# Export selected view rows and selected columns to excel

Tags: 8, importing-exporting, views

I use [VBO export](https://www.drupal.org/project/vbo_export) module and [Views Bulk Operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) module to export my view results to CSV. This works fine. The user can also make a selection which rows to export.

Is there a solution to let the user also select which columns (which view fields) will be exported to CSV?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

To export just a particular column or number of particular columns you would change the view itself. To preserve the original one, just copy the view export only the column(s) you need and delete the temporary view.

Comment: but I am looking for a way the user will be able to select the columns on the fly. Is that what you mean?